# Setting up a proxy using Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy

Is there any way to configure your ubuntu server as a proxy, so that proxy could be used in browsers, for example. server A. IP: `11.22.33.44` is a proxy and Using firefox or any browser we could use that IP for using internet?

Comment: I'm sure Volkswagen is happy that you put one of their IP's on the internet instead of using your own. (http://whois.domaintools.com/148.203.12.139)

Comment: Your question is thoroughly unclear, please ask a proper, defined and well-formed question if you expect others to help. If you want help "setting up a proxy using Ubuntu" you should do as the squid-cache documentation suggests: start with a simple, working, configuration and gradually add the extra features you need. If you then need help from this site, post your config, the expected behaviour and the errors you are encountering.

Comment: @mtak I totally added as frequent numbers, if that's really match somewhere with something then am  genius :)

Comment: @simlev updated. its clear now.

Comment: You could also chain some proxies e.g. privoxy, squid, tor, and then set the IP in your browsers. If local 127.0.0.1 or another IP somewhere else, to test e.g. a virtualmachine with bridged mode 192.168.1.X .

Comment: @JunaidFarooq It seems you are a genius: https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=11.22.33.44?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2 . RFC 5737 has a list of IP ranges for documentation use.

Comment: @mtak Ah thanks.. Do you have any answer the question?

Comment: Yes, several actually, but I haven't posted one, that's why I'm using the comments.

Comment: @mtak,, Okay then please post one. I need your help. I want to make my server proxy as well and then want to use it in a browser anywhere in this world.

Answer (score 0):

The question was edited and and can now be easily answered: **yes**. You can install a software proxy such a [squid-cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on the Ubuntu server and then configure your browser to use it. Squid-cache might not be the easiest program to correctly setup so do as the documentation suggests: start with a simple, working, configuration and gradually add the extra features you need. A how-to could help get you started, so have a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-squid-proxy-on-ubuntu-12-10-x64).

If it's a one-off or you only want to access a specific website or service from your server's ip, save yourself the hassle of setting up a proxy server and use port forwarding instead.

Comment: Okay I repeat myself. there is an server A and we want to make it proxy and use it on my local PC browser?